# Выдает ошибку, как решить?

Tags: javascript

Знакомая скинула фото, и попросила помочь. Я в js ничего не понимаю, ошибка и код на фото!.
Спасибо за помощь на перед[image: Ошибка]
[image: код]
[image: Как я понимаю ошибка номер 2...]

Comment: Нет слов. Вам же на украинском языке все написано что надо сделать, закомментируйте объявления переменных с помощью // в начале каждой строки. Это же учебная программа, все и так дано.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Leonid, так не на русском же ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Мне 9 лет вы о чем мужики, почему сразу так ((

Comment: @Blazy ну извини, злые мы, обидели ребенка. Другие дети сразу сообщают, что они дети и столько то лет, сейчас все сотру

Comment: @Grundy если подумать, то учебная программа не встает на уровень ученика. Комментарий - что это? Пояснение куска кода? Как можно пояснить строку кода с помощью //? А-а-а, он "отключает" строку кода... А зачем? Может лучше стереть эту строку и все? Для отладки? Какой отладки?.. Одним словом, если начинаешь с азов, то надо уметь забыть все свои глубокие практические знания и объяснять с нуля. Комментарии несут несколько полезных опций. Она из них - временное отключение части кода для целей отладки или сохранения какой-то логики, которую можно в дальнейшем включить. Но тут рано про это...

Comment: @Leonid, там на скриншотах еще есть кнопка "Теория" :) в которой должно быть как раз расписано, что, зачем и почему ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy, наверное так, я больше про то, что на стадии объявления переменных практической пользы от этого, возможно, не много. Просто понимания этих теоретических моментов не придет пока не практическая польза от этого будет не ясна. Можно было просто удалять строки кода, а потом возвращать написанное, а затем уже предложить способ легче - закомментировать. Или как-то так. Если непонятно, значит - плохо объяснено. Если не знают как пользоваться справочной информацией - плохо составлена логика интерфейса или самого курса. Это просто другая сторона, а так без мата сложно было читать вопрос)))

Comment: @Leonid, суть не в практической пользе, а в возможности сразу попробовать комментарии после объяснения ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ в данном случае не важно что комментировать, важен сам факт

Answer (score 1):

достаточно выполнить необходимые требования:
[image: текст на картинке решает проблему]

Answer (score 1):

#### Используйте `//` для создания однострочных комментариев.

Для решения задачи вначале строки поставьте два слэша, чтобы получилось так:

```
// const age = 36;
// const name = 'Klim';
```